# How to highlight all the occurrence of a particular string in a web page?

Tags: java, html, string, swing

I am writing a swing application. In this application there is a table with some HTTP links. When I click a row a new browser window opens. To this point everything works good.

Now I would like to know if it is possible to have all the occurrences of a particular string highlighted (when the new page opens).
In practice, how can I  implement programmatically something similar to the "find" and "highlight all".

Can you please give me just a starting point, so I can start working on this new feature?

Comment: *"Now I would like to know if it is possible to have all the occurrences of a particular string highlighted (when the new page opens)."*  Only if you control the web page, or the browser it is shown in.

Comment: @andrew, I embedded into my Swing app a class that implements a swing browser; then I added to this class a method that implements 'executeScript' and it works. Thanks Alb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve my issue,

1. I first added to my swing app a class that implements a swing browser. I just copied the code from Oracle:
   http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/SimpleSwingBrowser.java.htm
2. Then I put a call for this class into a listener:

   ```
   .addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
       public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
           String urlto = jTextField8.getText();
           String o = (String)jTable2.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRow, 1);
           String urltoencode = (urlto+"?find="+o); 
           SimpleSwingBrowser browser = new SimpleSwingBrowser(); 
           browser.setVisible(true);
           browser.loadURL(urltoencode);
   ```
3. In the end, I modified the Swing Browser Class;
   I just added some java script to be executed on the new page opened by the embedded browser:

   ```
   engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
           new ChangeListener<State>() {
           @Override
           public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
               if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                   engine.executeScript(
      "var myParam = location.search.split('find=')[1];"
    + "doSearch(myParam);function doSearch(text) {\n" +
      "        if (window.find && window.getSelection) {\n" +
      "        document.designMode = \"on\";\n" +
      "        var sel = window.getSelection();\n" +
      "        sel.collapse(document.body, 0);\n" +
      "\n" +
      "        while (window.find(text)) {\n" +
      "            document.execCommand(\"HiliteColor\", false, \"yellow\");\n" +
      "            sel.collapseToEnd();\n" +
      "        }\n" +
      "        document.designMode = \"off\";\n" +
      "    } else if (document.body.createTextRange) {\n" +
      "        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();\n" +
      "        while (textRange.findText(text)) {\n" +
      "            textRange.execCommand(\"BackColor\", false, \"yellow\");\n" +
      "            textRange.collapse(false);\n" +
      "        }\n" +
      "    }\n" +
      "}");
               }
           }
       });
   ```

Comment: So far so good, but in this solution the searched word is coded into the java script function. Next I want to pass the String to be searched from the Javafx app. But probably ... it is another question

Comment: Add parameter(s) to the URL.  E.G. instead of `http://my.com/index.html` use `http://my.com/index.html?find=string`.  Then you'll need to get the URL, break it down and discover the string to use for the search.

Comment: *"it is another question"*  Yep.  ;)

Comment: Interesting, I will have a go !!

Comment: Yay!  :)  Glad you got a working solution, and thanks for reporting back.  Any chance you can edit our comments into your answer so they are more obvious to later readers?

Comment: the line of code where is specified the URL becomes : browser.loadURL(urlto); where urlto is just the url + ?find=stringtosearch; the javascript code instead will change in .....executeScript(
                                    "var myParam = location.search.split('find=')[1];"
                                    + "doSearch(myParam);function ......; where myParam is just the last parameter from the browser link and pass it to the next function which execute the search. Alb

Comment: It is best to [edit the *answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30918398/edit) with details.

Comment: @Andrew why when I close the browser (opened in a new window) the swing app closes also ? p.s. answer edited with details ....

Comment: *"why when I close the browser (opened in a new window) the swing app closes also ?"* Best asked on a new question, but a warning sign is (probably) to be found in `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` .. ;)

Comment: I replayed too fast, It does not behave correctly, I opened a new question.